# Telnet/Send/Expect - Automatically pulling logs from a remote host

Tags: bash, tcl, send, telnet, expect

I have a simple BASH script I use that sends a `.esh` script to a remote host. For example, I know what the username and password is for the host, so my script does the following:

```
expect login:
send root\n
expect Password:
send abc123\n
expect "# "
```

So, this will automatically log me into the remote host as user `root` with password `abc123`.

I am now attempting to send a BASH-style one-line for loop to pull some metrics from some log files on the host, ie:

```
send 'for i in /var/log/example/*.txt; do echo $i; cat $i | grep error ; done \n'
```

However, this fails with:

```
# can't read "i": no such variable
    while executing
send 'for i in /var/log/example/*.txt; do echo $i; cat $i | grep error ; done \n'
```

I've read some similar posts, but I haven't found any case similar to this. Once I've figured out how to implement this, I will likely include more command-line commands to refine the output of the log files (ie: more bash temporary variables, pipe the output through `awk`, etc).

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Thank you.

---

EDIT: As per the provided answer, I changed my script to the following, and it worked like a charm:

```
expect login:
send root\n
expect Password:
send abc123\n
expect "# "
send { for i in /var/log/example/*.txt; do echo $i; cat $i | grep error ; done }
send "\n"
send exit
```

This logs into the remote host, prints some valuable metrics to the console, then quits telnet. I can now use a bash script on my local host to loop through multiple remote hosts via a text file containing a list of hostnames/IPs.

Thanks!

Comment: technically you should send with `\r` instead of `\n` -- `\r` is carriage return, I.e. "hitting enter"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quotes aren't used for quoting in [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), they're normal characters. Use double quotes if you want backslash, command and variable expansion, and curly braces if you don't.

Replace the first `'` with `{` and the last with `}`.